# How can I change the label of the title field "Name" of my taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

I want to customize the title label of my taxonomy, the name field. By default, its value is "Name".

I know I can use the `mymodule_form_alter` hook and do as followed:

```php
$form['title']['widget'][0]['#title'] = t('My Custom Name');
```

But I want to do it in the UI and export the configurations like any other fields. Also, I want to be able to translate my custom name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Base Field Override UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/base_field_override_ui), go to "Structures" > "Taxonomies" > "Manage fields" and go to the new "Base Field Override" tab. You can override the "Name" field here and translate it.